# MySQL database is going down once or twice a week, how do I diagnose?

Tags: mysql, logs

I have a linode.com account running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  On my server I have two instances of wordpress running with light traffic (100 to 400 users per day each) and an instance of Sendy (which is almost never used).  Once or twice a week, at random times, MySQL crashes and I get an error like database connection failed when I try to visit one of the wordpress sites (I'm not sure that is the exact error, I'm always in a rush to reboot the server to get the sites back online).

My question is, how can I figure out what's causing the issue?  How do I enable error logging and/or view the error logs?  Is there anything else I can do?

This is the MySQL version I'm running:

```
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                       |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.41                      |
| protocol_version        | 10                          |
| slave_type_conversions  |                             |
| version                 | 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                    |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                      |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu            |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I took a look inside the error.log and found these errors before the database went down last:

```
150518  0:47:26 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_771_0.MYI'; try to repair it
150518  0:47:26 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.41/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
150518  0:47:26 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_771_1.MYI'; try to repair it
150518  0:47:26 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.41/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
150518  2:45:33 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_771_0.MYI'; try to repair it
150518  2:45:34 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.41/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
150518  3:02:14 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_771_0.MYI'; try to repair it
150518  3:02:14 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.41/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
150518  3:33:57 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_771_0.MYI'; try to repair it
150518  3:33:57 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.41/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
150518  5:18:36 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

150518  5:18:36 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of threa 62546  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62545  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62544  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62543  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62542  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62541  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62540  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62539  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62538  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62537  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62536  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62535  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62533  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62532  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62531  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62530  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62529  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62528  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62527  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62526  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62525  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62524  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62523  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62522  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62521  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62520  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62519  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62518  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62517  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62516  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62515  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62514  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62513  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62512  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62511  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62510  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62509  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62508  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62506  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62505  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62504  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62503  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62502  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62501  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62500  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62499  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62498  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62497  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62496  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62495  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62494  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62493  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62492  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62491  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62490  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62489  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62488  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62487  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62486  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62485  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62484  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62483  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62482  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62481  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62479  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62478  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62477  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62475  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62474  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62473  user: 'wp_taptappower'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62472  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62471  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62470  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 62469  user: 'wp_honey'
150518  5:18:38 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 60305  user: 'wp_honey'

150518  5:18:39  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
150518  5:18:42  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 17372087869
150518  5:18:42 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150518  5:19:14 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please u$
150518  5:19:14 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150518  5:19:14 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150518  5:19:14 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150518  5:19:14 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150518  5:19:14 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150518  5:19:14 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150518  5:19:14 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150518  5:19:14 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
150518  5:19:15  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150518  5:19:16 InnoDB: 5.5.41 started; log sequence number 17372087869
150518  5:19:16 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
150518  5:19:16 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
150518  5:19:16 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
150518  5:19:16 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150518  5:19:16 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

You can see at 5:18:36 I restarted the server after waking up to an email about my sites being down.  :(

Comment: @Vérace Cool, thanks!  I have no problem taking a performance hit for a few days/week in order to find out what's causing the crashes.  How do I enable logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your traffic is very light, you could enable the general log which logs everything and use that to debug. WARNING this can adversely affect performance - test first at an off-peak time.

Following your comment on my comment, please find below what I have in my own my.cnf. As I said, be aware that this is a dev machine and not open to the web. Just keep a careful eye on your load when you do this.

```
general_log     = on
general_log_file= /home/pol/Downloads/software/mysql/5.6/inst/logfile.txt
```

[EDIT on rereading the question carefully]

I notice that you have a linode account and that they provide SSD drives - I'd recommend that you organise your system so that the general log is written to a new drive - which you can hire up until you find the origin of the problem? Obviously, this depends on how much revenue the sites are generating, but that's a business and not a technical decision.

[EDIT on further comments by the OP]

5:18:36 - WTF? I feel your pain! :-)

Check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-repair.html) out and especially the myisamchk utility [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisamchk.html). The fact that there is so much stuff about repairing MyISAM tables should tell you that the issue isn't unheard of! In any case, AIUI, MyISAM is being deprecated for the 5.7 releases - you really should think of converting to InnoDB!

[EDIT - to find filesystems and mountpoints]

from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-command-findout-on-which-partition-file-directory-exits/).

```
df
df /path/to/dir
df /path/to/file

In this example find out partition name for a file called /users/f/foo/file.txt, enter:

$ df -T /users/f/foo/file.txt
```

Normally, when you install Linux, it creates a /tmp partition - is this full on your system?

[EDIT - more about files/partitions &c.]

So, I'd keep the log on for the time being if I were you. Also, run a cron job every ~ 5mins to check how your /tmp is holding up. [Using du](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/22.html), you can keep track of individual files  - do something like date >> track_size.txt, then du -h >> track_size.txt just to keep an eye on things. Check [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-script-to-watch-the-disk-space.html). Run "man lsblk"  - it might also be of help.

Comment: Thanks!  I just uncommented those two lines in my my.cnf file.  I noticed that there is also ```log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log``` already uncommented.  I took a look inside and found some errors before the site went down.  I added the errors to my original question (above).

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I ran some checks and all my tables seem to be ok.  While searching I came across this question/answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3716778/1078829 that said my error might be something to do with the ```/tmp``` directory running out of space.  So I turned off the general logging and changed my my tmp directory to ```/var/tmp```.  Fingers crossed, I hope this fixes it.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: df -h should help you see if any partitions are running out of space.

Comment: Thanks.  Just took a look and ```/tmp``` doesn't exist when I run ```df -h```?  Maybe that was the issue...  I guess I'll know in a week or two if it worked.

Comment: df -P file/goes/here | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1 - so in your case df -P /tmp | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1 - then do df -h to see if it's tight on space. -h gives human readable. I've seen other methods to get this, but can't find them at the minute.

Comment: Check the "Mounted on" section of the result of df -h. I'd be surprised if /tmp wasn't there - it's **filesystem** is tmpfs - is that there. Check out my better command(s) in my edit.

Comment: Ok.  Cool.  Comes out to 65% used or 5.9G available.  Seems like plenty of space...

Comment: Check my further edit to my answer.